# Clean up [productivity] - close lots of closeworthy questions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, clean-up

[productivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/productivity) tag excerpt says:

> DO NOT USE (instead, see https://productivity.stackexchange.com/)

This tag was cleaned up as of [The Great Stack Overflow tag / question Cleanup of 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012), and it resides as of now. However, there are still a large amount of off-topic questions *and* the tag is still burnination-worthy.

I suggest that we go ahead and close all the unsalvageable questions and clean up questions where appropriate.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=[productivity]%20is:q%20closed:no%20locked:no

Answer (score 7):

All questions were cleaned up, retagged where it is appropriate, off-topic questions were flagged.

There are [no open questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=[productivity]%20is:q%20closed:no) left for this tag. I guess we can continue with burnination?

**Edit:**
Burnination is completed.